# Can a users Outlook calendar be displayed on an ASP.NET web page in an Intranet?

Tags: asp.net, outlook

Is it possible to embed an Outlook calendar on a web page in an Intranet?

If yes, do you just embed a code snippet and configure a few tags eg something that would take less than a day?
Or do you have to use an API, render your own HTML etc. which makes it a large job eg more than 2 days. We are experienced developers but have not done something like this before.

[image]